# PHP - query worked but the results are strange : all null

Tags: php, mysql

I use a data base ( created with phpmyadmin) in a function for my future website. The query worked but the result is strange : null .

This is my code :

```
public  function select_toutcompetences($requete){
    $query = "SELECT niv , nom   FROM competences  WHERE element = '$requete' ";
    $result = $this->_db->query($query);
    $tableau = array();

    if ($result->rowCount() == 0){
        return $tableau;
    } else {
        while($row = $result->fetch()) {
            $tableau[] = new Competence($row->niv,$row->nom);
        }
        return $tableau;
    }
}
```

In my view :

```
<?php if (!empty($table)) {?>
 <table>
  <caption>Les compétences</caption>
  <tr>
    <th>Niveau</th>
    <th>Nom</th>
<tr>
<?php foreach ($table as $i=> $element) { ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $element->niveau()?></td>
<td><?php echo $element->nom()?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
<?php }?>
```

With a var_dump , I got this :

```
object(Competence)[5]
 private '_niveau' => null
 private '_nom' => null

 null
```

My class :

```
<?php

class Competence {
private $_niveau;
private $_nom;
public function Livre($niveau,$nom) {
    $this->_niveau = $niveau;
    $this->_nom = $nom;
}

public function niveau() {
    return $this->_niveau;
}

public function nom() {
    return $this->_nom;
}
}
```

?>

Thanks you for your help. I searched but I didn't understand why it doesn't work.
PS : I know my query isn't securized. I would it to work first.

Edit : the sql data base : [comptences.sql](http://www.petit-fichier.fr/2015/03/14/competences/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your class does not have constructor. Method Livre is not called when object is initiating `$tableau[] = new Competence($row->niv,$row->nom);`. Try this (I have replaced Livre with __construct):

```
<?php

class Competence {
    private $_niveau;
    private $_nom;

    public function _contruct($niveau,$nom) {
         $this->_niveau = $niveau;
         $this->_nom = $nom;
    }

    public function niveau() {
        return $this->_niveau;
    }

    public function nom() {
        return $this->_nom;
    }
}
```

Also be sure you have same values in database result.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the variables in your class public as well.

```
public $_niveau;
public $_nom;
```